# Aspell under Emacs - multiple dictonaries

Tags: emacs, spell-checking, aspell

I'm using Aspell as a spelling checker for Emacs.
I know that, as a standalone, aspell can handle multpiple dictionaries (using `extra-dicts` param), but how to configure it under Emacs?

I know very little of emacs lisp... Could I provide some "ispell extra-args" in .emacs file? Would that work? If so I'd really appreciate simple example - I know very little of lisp syntax and absolute/relative paths it handles and etc.

The reason why I need this is that I sometimes write some documentation in Polish with English words in it. That makes `spell-check-region` much less attractive task than it is using single language in a file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that **aspell** is set as your `ispell-program-name` (you can do this in customize).

( Add these to your `.emacs` or `.emacs.d/init.el` )

You can add multiple dictionaries to the `ispell-dictionary-alist` (syntax is a bit complex, get more info in Emacs help with: <kbd>C-h v</kbd> `ispell-dictionary-alist`)

Example.

```
 '(ispell-dictionary-alist (quote (
       ("english" "[A-Za-z]" "[^A-Za-z]" "[']" nil ("-B") nil iso-8859-1)
       ("polish" "[A-Za-z¡£¦¬¯±³¶¼¿ÆÊÑÓæêñó]" "[^A-Za-z¡£¦¬¯±³¶¼¿ÆÊÑÓæêñó]" "" nil ("-d" "polish") nil iso-8859-2)
       ))
  )
```

You could also bind dictionary swapping to the keyboard.

e.g.

```
    (global-set-key (kbd "M-8") 
            (lambda () 
              (interactive) 
              (ispell-change-dictionary "american" nil))) ; "british" and "english" are also valid.
```

Comment: it did not work for me. For some reason it cannot load italian dictionary even if aspell works correctly with italian dictionary from command line.